# Where to install the bootloader? Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning, windows-8, bootloader

So I have decided to attempt to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows 8.1 Lenovo E545. I was following this guide http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-8-ubuntu.html. I was looking at my partition table and saw something odd. The boot loader isn't on the /dev/sda1 it appears to be on /dev/sda2 unlike in the tutorial. I am not a partition genius so should i install it on sda2 or sda1 like the tutorial says?

here is a picture of the partitions [http://imgur.com/OFouh7P](https://imgur.com/OFouh7P)

Comment: Sda2 is fine. Your BIOS will look for the "boot" flag partition (sda2) first. If it can't find that then it will go to the first bootable partition that works.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8.1 on Surface Pro 3, we found it was very important to choose the EFI partition (for us also /dev/sda2 (not default /dev/sda).  If not, the GRUB menu did not appear.

Another helpful hint for Surface Pro 3.  When is loads directly to Windows, to get to Ubuntu you can also go to Update and Recovery screen and then select Restart Now.  This brings up menu of ways to restart.  One of them is Use Device.   Besides USB, the Ubuntu distribution comes up as an option.  We have been using this as work-around (before we did re-stall and chose EFI Partition, which seems to have fixed the problem.)   Hope that helps!